# How can the size of a view change?

Tags: android

I was wondering what the purpose of the function onSizeChanged() is while building custom components. I was going over the tic tac toe sample, and can't really seem to get why it is needed, and how the size of a view can change. Sorry if this is a stupid question :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest answer is the case, when you add text to a `TextView`. More text should increase the size of a `TextView` if the width/heigth is set to `wrap_content`.